# TextInputLayout not working on 5.0

Tags: android

I was trying to implement Textinput layout in android, and I was using the following snippet.

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2.45"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
           >

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/TextLabel_floating"
                > 
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/rack_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:hint="@string/vin_or_stock_small"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/common_edit_text_dimen"
                android:maxLines="1"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

           <!--   <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.4"
                android:background="@drawable/textbox_right_radius"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/searchBtn">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
                    android:src="@drawable/cc_search"
                    android:background="@drawable/textbox_grey"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>-->
        </LinearLayout>
```

its working fine on every other device except the devices which have the os version 5.0. I tried many styles and it is not working, Can someone help me to solve this issue

Corresponding java code:

```
      mRackId = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.rack_id); 
      activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.
      LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
     mRackId.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                    if(mRackId.getText().length()!=0) {
                        if(NetworkUtils.getInstance().isNetworkAvailable()) {
                            LoadData(mRackId.getText().toString());
                        }else {
                            showErrorDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.network_connection_not_available));
                        }

                    }else{

                        showErrorDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.enter_valid_rack));
                    }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Question edited

Comment: Solved this yet ?